# Execute unoconv commant in php script

Tags: php, linux, uno

I want to develop a functionality where users can upload their presentation files (*.ppt) and after uploading we will convert those ppt in the pdf.

I was trying it using unoconv,

unoconv -f pdf presentation.ppt

through the command it runs successfully and convert the uploaded (*.ppt) file into (*.pdf) file.

But when i am trying to do this through php script, it fails.

exec(unoconv -f pdf presentation.ppt);

please help, thanks for your answers in advance.

Thanks
Atul

Answer (score 0):

Try using `exec("unoconv -f pdf presentation.ppt");`

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have already used this forgot to mention "" in the exec(""); statement. 
Can we provide the full path of presentation.ppt file.
if yes then where will the pdf file generated.

Comment: Yes you can try, after that run locate pdf file to find pdf file location

Comment: Hi I have used it but, couldn't get success.
Warning: -headless is deprecated. Use --headless instead.
Warning: -invisible is deprecated. Use --invisible instead.
Warning: -nodefault is deprecated. Use --nodefault instead.
Warning: -nofirststartwizard is deprecated. Use --nofirststartwizard instead.
Warning: -nologo is deprecated.  Use --nologo instead.
Warning: -norestore is deprecated.  Use --norestore instead.
Warning: -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext is deprecated. Use --accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext instead.